# how to add tooltip on hover over the stacked Labels in highcarts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

is there any way to add tooltip to the stackedLabels in highcharts, like in the below example:
I have male, female as my stack names and I am dispalying them at the bottom of the chart..however in case they are long names, I'm adding ellipsis, in such case is there a way to see the entire name on hover inside tooltip?
fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rq8m7e0v/

code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', "getete"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
     
       
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y:90,
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return this.stack;
            }
          
        }
    },
 
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
 series: [{
          name: 'John',
          data: [53, 33, 43,63,7,83],
          stack: 'male'
        }, {
          name: 'Joe',
          data: [33, 43,43,63,73,8],
          stack: 'female'
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [42, 54,43,62,74,84],
          stack: 'male',
        
        }, {
          name: 'Janet',
          data: [34, 40, 42,36,74,83],
          stack: 'female',
        }]
});
```

Comment: Hi @user1234, What exactly you want to show in such tooltip? Related data point or only the entire stack label name?

Comment: @ppotaczek: yes the stack label name- sonce I'm adding ellipsis to the long stack names- i'd want to show the full long names on hover inside the tooltip- is that possible. I couldnt find it directly as any method in highhcarts- so im not sure how to achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't have built-in tooltip for stack label, but still you can create your own tooltip for that. It's simple to add custom events to legendItem (mouseover and mouseout for example) and show that tooltip.

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var stackLabels = this.yAxis[0].stacking.stackTotalGroup.element.children,
      somePoint = this.series[0].points[0],
      chart = this;

    for (let i = 0; i < stackLabels.length; i++) {
      stackLabels[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        // show custom tooltip
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/orqyLjct/

**API:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: @ppotaczek- thanks for the help, however is there a way I can only show the name of the stack and not the entire series info. so currently in the above fiddle I can see all the column info but not the stack name i.e: "male" "female". any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Hi @user1234, Sorry for misunderstanding, that is not possible by default in Highcharts and you need to use a lot of custom code. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/60t5do1y/